# How to set multiple object value with special key on react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i need your help to set the new value in multiple object. I had object like this:

```
constructor(props){ 
 this.state = {   
  objData : [{
    score:{q1:null,q2:null,q3:null},
    data:{id:123, name:"Steven CHS"}
    },
    {
    score:{q1:null,q2:null,q3:null},
    data:{id:124, name:"Christian"}
    },
  ]
 }
}
```

and i would like to change the value by key q1,q2, anda q3. When i tried to use destructor like this, it's not working.

```
const handleChangeScore = (e,type,id) =>{
      const cScore = e.target.value;  
      this.setState((state) => {
          return {
              objData: state.objData.map((item) => {
              if(item.data.id !== e.target.name) return item;
              else return {...item.score.q1, cScore};
            })
          };
      });
}
```

this is the JSX where `handleChangeScore()` is used:

```
this.state.objData .map((v,index)=>(
    <tr>
        <td>{index+1}</td>
        <td>{v.data.id} - {v.data.name}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name={v.data.id} className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>handleChangeScore(e,"q1",v.data.id)} defaultValue={(v.score.q1) ? v.score.q1 : 0} /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name={v.data.id} className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>handleChangeScore(e,"q2",v.data.id)} defaultValue={(v.score.q2) ? v.score.q2: 0} /></td>
    </tr>                                                
))
```

The problem is when i use destructor to change the value on multiple object with specific key its not work or not change the value. Can anyone help me to fix my code ? Here's the full code in [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-matan-y6k6x?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to be fixed

1. Your `item.data.id` is number and `e.target.name` is string. To compare them without type comparison use `!=` instead of `!==`.
2. The `else` block should be corrected as below.

```
  handleChangeScore = (e, type, id) => {
    const cScore = e.target.value;
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        objData: state.objData.map((item) => {
          if (item.data.id != e.target.name) return item;
          else {
            return { ...item, score: { ...item.score, [type]: cScore } };
          }
        })
      };
    });
  };
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bird-orp2w)

Comment: @Febry Fairuz, check this out !!

Comment: Wow... thx for your help dud..

Answer (score 0):

Try below code no need to use `map()`. just pass the `index` in `this.handleChangeScore()` function !

And put `handleChangeScore()` this function in outside of `render()` !

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objData: [
        {
          score: { q1: null, q2: null, q3: null },
          data: { id: 123, name: "Steven CHS" }
        },
        {
          score: { q1: null, q2: null, q3: null },
          data: { id: 124, name: "Christian" }
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleChangeScore = (value, index, childObj) => {
    this.state.objData[index].score[childObj] = value;
    this.setState(this.state);   
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <table border="1">
          {this.state.objData.map((v, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <td>
                {v.data.id} - {v.data.name}
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name={v.data.id}
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeScore(e.target.value, index, "q1")}
                  defaultValue={v.score.q1 ? v.score.q1 : 0}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name={v.data.id}
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeScore(e.target.value, index, "q2")}
                  defaultValue={v.score.q2 ? v.score.q2 : 0}
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @Febry Fairuz, check my answer ! no need use `map()`